# syntax error in postgresql using Jupiter notebook

Tags: sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

How to overcome this eyntax error:

Here is my code:

```
%%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vio_table;
CREATE TABLE vio_table AS
Select A.VIOLCODE AS VIOLCODE,A.COUNT3 AS COUNT3, B.vio_count As TOTAL From    
(Select VIOLCODE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT3
From   new_webextract 
Group By VIOLCODE
) As A
Inner Join (
Select Count(*) As vio_count
From   new_webextract
) as B
```

Here is the error:

```
 * postgresql://docker:***@nycinspection.tditrain.com:5433/NYCinspection
Done.
(psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at end of input
LINE 10: ) as B
               ^

[SQL: CREATE TABLE vio_table AS
Select A.VIOLCODE AS VIOLCODE,A.COUNT3 AS COUNT3, B.vio_count As TOTAL From    
(Select VIOLCODE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT3
From   new_webextract 
Group By VIOLCODE
) As A
Inner Join (
Select Count(*) As vio_count
From   new_webextract B 
) as B]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Can please tell me what is the syntax error and how to resolve it?

Comment: A `JOIN` needs a [join condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) specified with `ON`

Comment: No `;` at end of `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: I tried the semi-colon still gives the error.

Comment: You are right. On works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are doing the cartesian join to repeat the total for every row. In that case, it's probably easier to write a CTE for your total and query like this.

```
create table vio_table as 
(
    with vio_total as (
      select count(*) as total
      from new_webextract
      )
    select a.violcode, count(a.*) as count3, b.total
    from new_webextract a, vio_total b
    group by a.violcode, b.total
);
```

| violcode | count3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 10 |
| b | 1 | 10 |
| c | 3 | 10 |
| d | 4 | 10 |

The same results can be obtained from joining to a count query, but I've never liked these as they can be difficult to read when multiple are present.

```
select a.violcode, count(a.*) as count3, b.total
from new_webextract a, 
 (select count(*) as total from new_webextract)b
group by a.violcode, b.total;
```